# How to draw "pouring" effect in gdi+?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, gdi+

See the pic:

[image]

I know gradients, but in this pic, the gradient border is irregular, just like pouring water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to a "gradient" -- there is a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class that you can use for this purpose; you can also find an example on MSDN: [Creating a Linear Gradient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533914%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I think its more like "where the DrawGlossyButton() call ?" type of question.

Comment: i know gradient, but this pic, the gradient border is irregular, just like pouring water.

Comment: @lovespring: What do you mean by irregular? Are you referring to the rounded corners?

Comment: no, the white gradient brush's top border is irregular. so, i cannot draw a rectangle and fill the rectangle, it's not a regular rectangle.

Comment: @lovespring: How exactly is the "irregular area" defined? In the screenshot that you posted, I think the gradient is just an image. If you can somehow define a region that bounds the white portion, you can use [`FillRegion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535690%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to fill it using the gradient brush.

Comment: this image is a snapshot from word2010, I think the white area is all done by gdi+ function call, not from a image.